# headers footers

Tags: fancyhdr, fancybox

How to have a full box that covers the edge of a paper instead of having to define `\lhead{} \chead{} \rhead{}, \lfoot{} \cfoot{} \rfoot{}`. Also the foot is not at the edge of paper neither the head. How to adjust the boxes to cover the edges. Also what is the command to draw a vertical box vbox at the left and one at the right that covers the edge of the paper. What I want is draw a color box that covers the edge of the paper so my `lipsum` would stay inside.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}         % Latin Modern fonts
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{
  height=180mm,
  width=180mm,
 left=0mm,
 right=0mm,
 top=0mm,
headheight=0mm, 
textheight=20cm,
 }
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead{\parbox[b][21mm][c]{10cm}{\tcboxfit[colback=blue,colframe=blue,width=10cm,height=2cm,fit basedim=20pt,fit fontsize macros,valign=center,frame style={fill=blue}]{\centering \textcolor{white}{\bfseries Test Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.}}}}
\chead{\parbox[b][21mm][c]{10cm}{\tcboxfit[colback=blue,colframe=blue,width=10cm,height=2cm,fit basedim=20pt,fit fontsize macros,valign=center,frame style={fill=blue}]{\centering \textcolor{white}{\bfseries Test Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.}}}}
\lfoot{\parbox[b][21mm][c]{10cm}{\tcboxfit[colback=red,colframe=red,width=10cm,height=2cm,fit basedim=20pt,fit fontsize macros,valign=center,frame style={fill=red}]{\centering \textcolor{white}{\bfseries Test Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.}}}}
\rfoot{\parbox[b][21mm][c]{10cm}{\tcboxfit[colback=red,colframe=red,width=10cm,height=2cm,fit basedim=20pt,fit fontsize macros,valign=center,frame style={fill=red}]{\centering \textcolor{white}{\bfseries Test Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.}}}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: do you really want `textheight=20cm` and `height=180mm`?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

Is this the kind of design you need:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}         % Latin Modern fonts
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hmargin=1cm, vmargin=3cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{layout} % checking things


\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}


\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{picture}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
    \put(0,\paperheight){\raisebox{-\height}{\tcboxfit[colback=blue, colframe=blue,
    width=10cm, height=2cm, fit basedim=20pt, fit fontsize macros, frame
    style={fill=blue}]{\centering \textcolor{white}{\bfseries Test Lorem ipsum
        dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
        vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.}}}}%
%
    \put(\paperwidth,\paperheight){\llap{\raisebox{-\height}{\tcboxfit[colback=blue, colframe=blue,
    width=10cm, height=2cm, fit basedim=20pt, fit fontsize macros, frame
    style={fill=blue}]{\centering \textcolor{white}{\bfseries Test Lorem ipsum
        dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
        vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.}}}}}%
%
    \put(\paperwidth,0){\llap{\tcboxfit[colback=red, colframe=red,
    width=10cm, height=2cm, fit basedim=20pt, fit fontsize macros, frame
    style={fill=red}]{\centering \textcolor{white}{\bfseries Test Lorem ipsum
        dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
        vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.}}}}%
%
    \put(0,0){\tcboxfit[colback=red, colframe=red,
    width=10cm, height=2cm, fit basedim=20pt, fit fontsize macros, frame
    style={fill=red}]{\centering \textcolor{white}{\bfseries Test Lorem ipsum
        dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
        vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.}}}%
}


\begin{document}
%\layout
\lipsum[1-18]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Perhaps according to comments you are more after something like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}         % Latin Modern fonts
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hmargin=5cm, vmargin=3cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{layout} % checking things


\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}


\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{picture}

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
% HEAD
    \put(0,\dimexpr\paperheight-2cm\relax){\tcboxfit[colback=blue, colframe=blue,
    width=\paperwidth, height=2cm, fit basedim=20pt, fit fontsize macros, frame
    style={fill=blue}, sharp corners]{\centering \textcolor{white}{\bfseries Test Lorem ipsum
        dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
        vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.}}}%
%
% FOOT
    \put(0,0){\tcboxfit[colback=red, colframe=red,
    width=\paperwidth, height=2cm, fit basedim=20pt, fit fontsize macros, frame
    style={fill=red}, sharp corners]{\centering \textcolor{white}{\bfseries Test Lorem ipsum
        dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
        vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.}}}%
% %
% LEFT VERTICAL (width=4cm, inner margin = 0.5cm each side)
  \put(0,2cm){\fboxsep0pt \colorbox{green}{\kern.5cm\parbox[b][\dimexpr\paperheight-4cm][c]{3cm}{\bfseries
        \RaggedRight\color{white}Test Lorem ipsum
        dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
        vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Test Lorem ipsum
        dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
        vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Test Lorem ipsum
        dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
        vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Test Lorem ipsum
        dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
        vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Test Lorem ipsum
        dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
        vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. }\kern.5cm}}
%
% RIGHT VERTICAL (width=4cm, inner margin = 0.5cm each side)
  \put(\dimexpr\paperwidth-4cm,2cm){\fboxsep0pt \colorbox{magenta}{\kern.5cm\parbox[b][\dimexpr\paperheight-4cm][c]{3cm}{\bfseries
        \RaggedLeft\color{white}Test Lorem ipsum
        dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
        vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Test Lorem ipsum
        dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
        vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Test Lorem ipsum
        dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
        vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Test Lorem ipsum
        dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
        vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Test Lorem ipsum
        dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
        vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. }\kern.5cm}}
%
}


\begin{document}
%\layout
\lipsum[1-18]
\end{document}
```

Produces

[image]
Notice I have used simple parboxes for the side with no font scaling. And possibly the top and bottom could also be done with `\scalebox` avoiding usage of `tcolorbox` package.

It is not clear to me if this is expected design. The page number will need some handling, perhaps moving it higher up thanks to geometry options.

Comment: Thanks jfbu I need also the same boxes at left and right of the paper. How to get rid of rounded corners ?

Comment: add `sharp corners` option to `\tcboxfit`. Notice that in such cases much lower weight methods than loading `tcolorbox` package exist. (using `\scalebox` and `\colorbox`) Do you really want the contents to be scaled? I don't understand what you mean by "same boxes at left and right". Do you mean rotated 90 degrees?

Comment: I want lipsum to be inside a colored box that covers the edge of the paper. inside each box, there is a small note. So for vertical box at the left of the lipsum the text inside has to be written vertically and at the right the same.

Comment: this is really not clear (to me), how many boxes? how come is the lipsum (=main text) a "small note". Best would be to enhance your question with expected result done in Word or other software.

Comment: (http://hpics.li/1f84da8) The lipsum is inside box that has 1 color for head (blue) one color for foot (red), one color vertical at left (green) and one color vertical at right.

Comment: Thanks. This what I want. How to write text in a vertical box in a vertical way?